# Ubuntu server 18.04 not overwriting home dir on install?

Tags: server, partitioning, home-directory

I have a 16.04 install with `/` and `/home` on separate partitions; I would like to install Ubuntu server 18.04 on the `/` partition without wiping out the `/home` partition; this is possible with a xubuntu desktop iso installer, but apparently not with the Ubuntu live server 18.04 iso; it just deletes all partitions as if the disk is empty; on the positive side, it correctly partitions a new disk and installs the efi partition correctly and it is actually bootable; no need to run `sudo grub-install` after the install from a live USB to make the new install boot.

Comment: not quite a duplicate; I know how to select something else and choose which partitions to install/format using the xubuntu desktop installer for example; in this question, I tried the ubuntu-18.04-live-server-amd64.iso which does not have such an option; I didn't see the ubuntu-18.04-server-amd64.iso at that time, which I now tried, and it does let you select which partitions to use/format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would make a backup of your home directory and save the /etc and /var/log directory.

In the Ubuntu 18.04 installer you have to choose in the partition menu **something else**.

the ubuntu server image name that allows you to choose which existing partition(s) to use and how, similar to the xubuntu desktop installer, is

```
    ubuntu-18.04-server-amd64.iso
```

Comment: I added the server iso image name to your answer which enables you to choose which existing partition(s) to use: ubuntu-18.04-server-amd64.iso; the image I tried before which does not have this option is ubuntu-18.04-live-server-amd64.iso

Comment: Please don't post links to youtu.be but type the text of the steps to take hare so your answer comes up in google search results.